# Deploy "WAR" with Tomcat issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, tomcat7, war

I am using:

1. Ubuntu 12.04
2. JRuby 1.7.2
3. Rails 3.2.12
4. Tomcat 7.0.26

I have successfully run my application using

```
rails server
```

command and work with my demo application on **127.0.0.1:3000** .

I have installed **warble** gem and using

```
warble
```

in my application directory generates .war file which I have deployed. Unfortunately, when I try to reach my application using **127.0.0.1:8080/depot/** I get the following error:

> org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) cannot load Java
>   class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver   at
>   org.jruby.javasupport.JavaClass.for_name(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaClass.java:1227)
>   ...................

So, I believe the application is not able to find the specified driver but how I am supposed to deploy it?

Also, using Tomcat in this way, will be my application visible from remote PCs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have you installed the db2 database drivers into the Tomcat shared resources folder?  Or are they deployed as part of the .war ?
2. The simple answer is no.  127.0.0.1 always routes to localhost;  You would need to define a new virtualhost in the TomCat configuration in order to expose your application to the outside world.

Comment: Thanks. I guess sometimes the reading can not be avoid. I started to read the Tomcat documentation and find what I need there.